# Problem in installing rattle package in R : both with RGtk2 and R version

Tags: r, rattle, rgtk2

Trying to install rattle package after several years, I faced several unexpected and weird errors. Using the latest version of R, RGtk2 package could not be installed and when back to previous versions, I got such an error for version 3.5 to 4.0:

```
Warning message:
package ‘rattle’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)
```

I read different posts and solutions both on the SO and other places but I could not install it.

Is there any idea and tip to do so successfully?

---

**Update**

Recently in March 2022, rattle is removed from cran and new installation guide presented on its [official website](https://rattle.togaware.com/).
I followed the instruction and tried to install rattle on the latest version of R and got the following error.

[image]

---

**Update 2**
Followed the solution by @tc90kk, the rattle and all the dependencies have been installed but RGtk2.

```
Error in rattle() : 
  The RGtk2 package is not available but is required. 
  Please install the package using, for example: 

   install.packages("RGtk2")
```

Trying to install RGtk2 using the latest manual on [Togaware](https://rattle.togaware.com/) as:

```
install.packages("https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-12-15/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.zip", repos=NULL)
```

this error raised:

```
    trying URL 'https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-12-15/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.zip'
Error in download.file(p, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-12-15/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.zip'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(p, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The connection with the server was reset'
```

Comment: Have you been tried installing from local files (zip packages)?

Comment: @Rwy5, I tried but faced some errors again :(

Comment: MRAN was down for a while. All seems okay now.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this worked:
`remotes::install_github("cran/rattle")`

Comment: did you try to run `rattle::rattle()`? What is your R version?

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I updated OP according to your suggestion. Please take a look at it.

Comment: @Waldi, do you have any suggestion for installing RGtk2?

Comment: @Eilia, unfortunately this is where I also got stuck ;-(

Comment: @Waldi, OK and thank you. I never thought a simple installation turns into a nightmare! Forgot to mention, could you install rattle package recently?

Comment: @Eilia, no I was never able to install `rattle` (under R>4.0)

Comment: @Waldi, I tried to install rattle on R < 4 but faced an error: not available for that version.

Answer (score 1):

Rattle and RGtk2 were both recently archived on CRAN.

I understand from the RGtk2 author that RGtk2 continues to operate just fine.

Also Rattle is making it's way back on to CRAN at this moment.

In the meantime, please follow the instructions at

https://rattle.togaware.com

I have just tested this again and it worked for me.

Hope this assists those having issues installing Rattle just now.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can it be installed properly on Win 7, too?

Comment: I tried to install rattle on R 3.5.2 and faced this error:

Warning: unable to access index for repository https://rattle.togaware.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://rattle.togaware.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘rattle’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)